# How to load a JS function every 1000px when scrolling down a page?

Tags: javascript

When I am scrolling down a page, how do I automatically execute a JS function every 1000 px?

Nothing should happen if the user scrolls down by less than 1000 px, then up by the same amount.

This is the call of the function that I want to execute:

```
    refresh('refresh_status', 'refresh_status.php', '', '', '', 'refresh');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? do you mean "execute"? What should happen if the user scrolls 900px down, then 900px up?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes i mean to "execute", if the user scroll down and then he's scroll up, nothing happens

Comment: `refresh` is not a standard function. are you using a framework?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, look into jQuery waypoints

Comment: @JanDvorak refresh its just a name of ajax function. this function is not of jQuary

Comment: Then it is `window.onscroll` and some coding

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks for helping me! =] i dont really know how to work with this "window.onscroll"

Comment: I think you are all being harsh because of the sample code Idoroni has posted. I believe that is just a snippet of code found somewhere else and is not being suggested as a solution. Cut a little slack here. The actual wording of the suggestion makes sense and there are several good answers below that solve the question as stipulated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with a bit of jQuery!

```
var win = $(window),
    sectionHeight = 1000,
    currentSection = 0,
    $result = $('#result');

function myFunction(n) {
    $result.append('<p>FUNCTION CALLED ' + n + '</p>')
}

win.scroll(function (e) {
    var calculateSection = parseInt(win.scrollTop() / sectionHeight, 10);
    if (currentSection !== calculateSection) {
        currentSection = calculateSection;
        myFunction(currentSection);
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/KsNcz/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't want to use jQuery, as the initial post tag is only javascript.
Here is the code to detect the current height according to scroll event, it's cross platform too:

```
function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers except IE before #9
        return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
        var docBody = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var docElement= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        docElement = (docElement.clientHeight)? docElement : docBody ;
        return docElement.scrollTop;
    }
}

window.onscroll = function (oEvent) {
    var currentScrollTop = getScrollTop(); // current position in pixels from top
    // do whatever you want here at the pixel height which you desire
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery with relative ease.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    var count = 1;
    var windowPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( windowPosition === count*1000 ){
        myFunction();
        count++;
        };
});
```